# How does apple mail deal with 2FA

Tags: iphone, mail.app, security, two-factor-authentication

I recently set up 2fa on some emails and chose google authenticator as the second method. These providers are outlook and gmail.

When I use thunderbird on linux mint, I need to generate an app password to log in. Sometimes these passwords seem to expire but this is not my question, only a ”proof” that 2fa really is turned on, and that google auth isn’t only an optional sign-in method.

**Mail on iphone** (SE 2020, os 14.6) always works at first setup, never failing, despite only knowing my login password (both two providers). What is going on here? Am I dealing with a feature or a vulnerability?

Here is what I’ve considered but failed to query here or on google.
A) the smart phone connects to the server very often, therefore the app password does not expire

B) the smart phone always looks up one-time passwords on google authenticator, performing repeated logins that I do not see

C) the smart phone is a ”trusted device” that can somehow ignore 2fa

If this is a vulnerability, I would like to know if it is serious. If it is a feature, are there methods to implement it on other devices (e.g. ubuntu pc)

Edit: I’m really asking **why does mail (software) even work**. Removed a reference to icloud as irrelevant.

Comment: Are Gmail and Outlook accounts even supposed to work with 2FA from Apple Mail, or do you need to create application-specific passwords?

Comment: I enabled 2fa in gmail and outlook in their respective online settings and have needed to authenticate to login afterwards. I also need to login using an app password on thunderbird but not apple mail, in fact I never typed an app password on my phone (there is only one that exists). If they aren’t supposed to work, shouldn’t apple mail give me errors instead of fully functioning mail boxes?

Comment: I'm sure it's supposed to work :-) I'm more wondering why it doesn't work for you, not sure 2FA is really the problem here

Comment: Yeah I may be asking the wrong question entirely. Hopefully I’ll get some pointers before the question gets pruned :p

Comment: Might be better to focus the question on the actual problem (which seems to be getting logged out on the Mac) than making too many assumptions already about a potential cause.

Comment: I edited to question to hopefully clarify what I’m asking.

Comment: @theotherfoxmulder In response to your clarification of the question, the answer is (C). The smart phone becomes a trusted device when you sign in the first time due to a special token being stored locally on the device.

Comment: @jksoegaard in this case I’m surprised that neither outlook nor gmail list my iphone as such, however, I can list my pc and allow thunderbird to work. But it seems most likely, your reply. I’ll draft another edit to see if I have a well-defined question at all, as many were confused. Unless you feel like answering in detail.

Comment: @Dan that is not the question, at all, which shows that my post is poor and confused. Probably my misinterpretation about 2fa,

Comment: Thus I removed my useless comment :).

Comment: It sounds like you’re expecting google to sign you out when you add 2FA, but that’s something you need to do explicitly either by signing out on your device or visiting https://myaccount.google.com/security - 2FA will be required for signing in. This is a feature, not a bug. The answer is C.

Comment: You also seem to be asking why Thunderbird requires an app password - that's just a limitation of that software, not necessarily related to the OS it runs on. They need to implement "Sign in with Google". More info: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833

Answer (score 2):

**I asked the wrong question based on a mistaken assumption**. That assumption was that Apple was somehow escalating privileged access. instead my problem was provider - 3rd party client problems, for example Microsoft kept disbanding app passwords by some unknown metrics. *Google just labeled some of them unreliable*, see:Geary.

I had mistakenly assumed 2fa to mean login pass *and authentication* ***always***. That just isn’t so - in fact I knew about ”trusted devices”, the confusion came from this tiny detail; my iphone wan’t listed as such a device, it could presumably be removed by ”revoke all” but I need mine operational 24/7 and daren’t risk it now. Based on comments, my hypothesis is that, if certain clients aren’t even trusted to handle the very basics, perhaps apple mail - on ios - on an iphone, was given a special token, a token with no set final date, always on, unless revoked. Oh and I did check that authenticator weren’t even required, on this phone. **The answer according to my options is C**, this is a trusted device. As for the token, I don’t know exactly. Input from apple server modified by some unique process to send the resulting output as proof of identity? But now I’ll know what I’m looking for, *it is not authenticator nor a manual prompt*. I suggested that the prompt was only needed once, but something similar might just be running under the hood.

**I mistakenly identified iphone as *single point of failure*, to be equal to untrustworthy**. And yes, it could establish a vulnerability in some cases, but I made a gross exaggerarion. So let’s compare it to a pc computer: 1) encryption as default vs optional,  2) optional login pass 3) biometrics. The phone has similar or better options and phones often have other architecture security benefits. Both devices use authenticators and password managers too. I can’t recall giving my iphone a special status, but I must have done so. After all it was a matter of 1) device pass login 2) google pass login 3) terms and confirmation 4) google prompt to confirm.

Two passwords and a 2nd factors, pretty good identification to me

**Potential issue: ease-of-use can be misread as lax sexurity, disfunctional logins can be misread as strong security**. Or wait was that just me? Can’t be just me

Summa summarum: my concept of 2fa was very rigid, I even misattributed flawed auth scenes to stricter security,

p.s I posted a horrible blog entry here that was illegible and incoherent. I’m struggling with record heat. Having regained some composure I’ll stop here and thank you for pointing the righr way.

Answer (score 1):

Both Mac and iOS Mail applications will bring up the Google login page for Gmail connections. Google processes the 2 Factor Auth and the Mail app doesn't need to worry about it. Gmail provides the Mail application with a token that it can use indefinitely.

Other applications that ask for your username and password in their own UI need an app-specific password since they don't get to take advantage of the Google-provided login flow.

Comment: At first sight it seems like the real answer. I will check up on it tomorrow, so that I can verify this somehow, or somebody else does / answers. I’m new and I understand it to be good form to wait for some time before accepting answer. I might also wanna re-read some faqs about this, such as, whether the lack of sources matter here. Thanks for your relevant insight.